FFMPEG in Node.js: Conversion Failed
I have a small node.js web app. I use like this in a get request:
app.get('/api/voice/:gender/:voice/:pitch', function(req, res){
        if(req.params.pitch == "1" || req.params.pitch == "1.0") {
            const file = "./voices/" + req.params.gender.toLowerCase() + "/" + req.params.voice + ".mp3"
            res.download(file);
            return
        }

        const inputFile = "./voices/" + req.params.gender.toLowerCase() + "/" + req.params.voice + ".mp3"
        const output_file = "./Audio/Temp/" + req.params.voice + ".mp3"
        ffmpeg()
                .input(inputFile)
                .audioCodec('pcm_s16le') // Set the audio codec to PCM with 16-bit depth
                .audioFrequency(44100) // Set the sample rate
                .on('error', function(err) {
                    console.error('Error while converting:', err);
                })
                .on('end', function() {
                    // res.download(output_file)
                })
                .save(output_file);

    });

It gives Conversion Failed error:
[2024-07-11T18:11:22.880Z] Error while converting: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Conversion failed!

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (d:\Dev\Anima\Client\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:180:22)
    at ChildProcess.emit (d:\Dev\Anima\Client\lib\events.js:519:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (d:\Dev\Anima\Client\lib\internal\child_process.js:294:12)
    at Process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {stack: 'Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Conversion …Trampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)', message: 'ffmpeg exited with code 1: Conversion failed!
'}

When I use same code in a node.js desktop(.exe) app, it successfully runs. When I use it in an express.js app, it fails. Error message is not clear. What is the issue?

If the output file is PCM, why do you give it an .mp3 extension?  Are you just copying whole files here?

I retrieved pcm_s16le part from another place because I convert an audio to 16 bit. My source file is mp3 and target file is wav. This worked for desktop app. I'm not sure what PCM is, another audio encoding maybe. If there's a more suitable method to achieve this, I'd appreciate to learn.

@cuneyttyler What exactly are you trying to do?  The formats you choose depend on what you're trying to do.  If you just want to pitch shift, you could do that client-side.  Also, your code is wide open to security vulnerabilities.  You're letting the user access pretty much whatever files they want on disk because you're allowing the user to specify the paths.

I have sound files (.mp3) that I'd like to pitch shift and serve with res.download(file).  The code doesn't change pitch but it's trivial after getting this work. About security, thank you for pointing out, if you have any suggestions, I'd like to hear. I'm a bit less knowledgable about security. @Brad

@cuneyttyler You should whitelist the possible options for :gender, and :voice so that someone can't just request something with a voice name of ../../../../../../etc/passwd or something else.  If they can only request from a certain list, where anything else returns a 403 or 404, then that solves it.  And, as far as output file goes, you can actually just stream STDOUT from FFmpeg to res rather than writing it to disk first.  I don't know how Fluent does it, but with just normal child_process, you just to proc.stdout.pipe(res).

PCM ("pulse coded modulation") is what an unencoded audio file is.  The values of each sample are 16-bit signed integers.  If the file is supposed to be a WAVE file, then give it a .wav extension.

Okay, so I figured that out as well. My output format was .mp3, I changed it to wav and it works.
